# Finding Context free grammar for L

Tags: automata, context-free-grammar

Find CFG for :
$$L=\left\{ w \in \left\{a,b,c \right\}^* \mid w=a^mb^nc^k  \ and \ (n=m \ or \ m\neq k) , m,n,k \in \mathbb{N_{0}}\right\}$$

I tried by dividing in cases:

1) $ w=a^nb^nc^k  , k \neq n $

2) $ w=a^mb^nc^k  , k \neq n \neq m$

3)  $ w=a^nb^nc^n $

The third case is not possible because it is not a context free language?
I am having trouble with the first case. I tried by dividing it in cases where $k < n $ and $k >n $, but got stuck because the grammar is supoosed to be similar to the case 3), the difference being in adding c-s.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Your language is the union of the languages $L_1c^*$, $L_2$ and $L_3$, where 
\begin{align}
L_1 &= \left\{ a^nb^n \mid  n \geqslant 0 \right\}, \\
L_2 &= \left\{ a^mb^nc^k \mid m > k \text{ and } m,n,k \geqslant 0 \right\}, \\
L_3 &= \left\{ a^mb^nc^k \mid m < k \text{ and } m,n,k \geqslant 0 \right\}
\end{align}

Comment: Would this be right then ?$$S \rightarrow S_1 \mid S_2 \mid S_3 \mid \epsilon$$
$$S_1 \rightarrow aS_1b$$
$$S_2 \rightarrow aS_2c \mid S_2b \mid aS_2 \mid a$$
$$S_2 \rightarrow aS_3c \mid bS_3 \mid S_3c \mid c$$

Comment: Almost correct. The first component should be a grammar for $L_1c^*$, not for $L_1$.

Comment: I found another mistake. In $S_{2}$ if you take $aS_{2}c$ then $S_{2}b$ and then again $aS_{2}c$ you get $aS_{2}cbc$ which is not in the language

Comment: So I would just add $B \rightarrow bB \mid \epsilon$ and for rewrite $S_{2}$ and $S_{3 } $ as : $$ S_{2} \rightarrow aS_{2}c \mid aS_{2} \mid B$$  $$ S_{3} \rightarrow aS_{3}c \mid S_{3}c \mid B$$

Comment: Yes, it looks good now. Well done.